# Script error (AnimatorHandler): Update() can not take parameters. error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

i follow Sebastian Graves dark souls tutorial but the problem is when i want to move the camera and moving the player as the same time it get moving random or the opposite side or something like that i stopped in ep2 cause of this bug and this is my code of animatorhandler sry for my bad english and im new at unity [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1GcD.png) and this is the photo i want to move left but it moved straight it kinda random so plz help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace SG
{
    public class AnimatorHandler : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Animator anim;
        int vertical;
        int horizontal;
        public bool canRotate;

        public void Initialize()
        {
            anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
            vertical = Animator.StringToHash("Vertical");
            horizontal = Animator.StringToHash("Horizontal");
        }

        public void Update(float verticalMovement, float horizontalMovement)
        {
            #region Vertical
            float v = 0;

            if (verticalMovement > 0 && verticalMovement < 0.55f)
            {

                v = 0.5f;
            }
            else if (verticalMovement > 0.55f)
            {
                v = 1;

            }
            else if (verticalMovement < 0 && verticalMovement > -0.55f)
            {
                v = -0.5f;
            }
            else if (verticalMovement < -0.55f)
            {
                v = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                v = 0;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Horizontal
            float h = 0;

            if (horizontalMovement > 0 && horizontalMovement < 0.55f)
            {
                h = 0.5f;
            }
            else if (horizontalMovement > 0.55f)
            {
                h = 1;
            }
            else if (horizontalMovement < 0 && horizontalMovement > -0.55f)
            {
                h = -0.5f;
            }
            else if (horizontalMovement < -0.55f)
            {
                h = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                h = 0;
            }

            #endregion

            anim.SetFloat(vertical, v, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
            anim.SetFloat(horizontal, h, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
        }

        public void CanRotate()
        {
            canRotate = true;
        }

        public void StopRotation()
        {
            canRotate = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I viewed the debug thing in his video and my root motion is unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error Update() can not take parameters indicates that you are trying to call the Update() method and pass parameters to it, when Update() does not accept any parameters.

The Update() method in Unity is a special method that gets called automatically by the engine every frame. It does not support custom parameters so just call Update() wihtout anything inside.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html

Exmaple:

```
public void Update() {
   float horizontalMovement = anim.GetFloat("HorizontalVelocity");
   float verticalMovement = anim.GetFloat("VerticalVelocity");
   #region Vertical
        float v = 0;
...
```

Comment: so what i need to change in my code cause im somewhat confused

Comment: ```public void Update(float verticalMovement, float horizontalMovement)``` this will not work. only ```public void Update()``` is allowed.

Comment: But now there is a question for you what are you expecting to have for verticalMovement or horizontalMovement since this is a custom naming from you. I assumed that it is the velocity that you want from the animation. If the answer is yes, than you can use ```float horizontalMovement = anim.GetFloat("HorizontalVelocity");
float verticalMovement = anim.GetFloat("VerticalVelocity");```

Comment: then i just put public void update under it i put the float thing u sent in the first thing right sry cause im so bad at c# so yeah